# Python Regex Invalid Expression

Tags: python, regex, nginx

My Python regex expression seem to match up on www.debuggex.com

```
(?P<host>[^ ]*) - - \[(?P<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?P<method>\S+)(?: +(?P<path>[^\"]*) +\S*)?" (?P<code>[^ ]*) (?P<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?P<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?P<agent>[^\"]*)")(?: (?P<request_time>[^ ]*) (?P<upstream_time>[^ ]*) (?P<pipe>[\.|p]))?
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZPTBKk2e8RFy0w1_)

but when parsing my nginx log file i get ****"Raise error, v #invalid expression"***  any ideas ?

```
#LOG FILE TO WATCH
filename = '/var/log/nginx/access.log'

    #REGULAR EXPRESSION
    regex = re.compile("""(?P<host>[^ ]*) - - \[(?P<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?P<method>\S+)(?: +(?P<path>[^\"]*) +\S*)?" (?P<code>[^ ]*) (?P<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?P<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?P<agent>[^\"]*)")(?: (?P<request_time>[^ ]*) (?P<upstream_time>[^ ]*) (?P<pipe>[\.|p]))?""", re.IGNORECASE | re.X )


    f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-F',filename],\
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = f.stdout.readline()
        print line
        results = regex.match(line)
        try:
            print results.groups(request_time)
        except:
            print "Your expression does not match  this line"
```

Example of a nginx log entry

```
174.168.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2014:09:41:13 +0100] "GET /share/proxy/data/slingshot/profile/avatar/jmears1/thumbnail/avatar32 HTTP/1.1" 200 1467 "<EXAMPLE URL>" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)" 0.050 0.050
```

**Update: i've removed "re.X" and replace it with "re.verbose"**

**Update: Debug output after removing "re.x"**

```
> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(30)<module>()
```

-> filename = '/var/log/nginx/access.log'

(Pdb) n

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(33)()
>   -> regex = re.compile("""(?P[^ ]*) - - [(?P[^]]*)]  "(?P\S+)(?: +(?P[^\"]*) +\S*)?" (?P[^ ]*) (?P[^ ]*)(?: "(?P[^\"]*)" "(?P[^\"]*)")(?: (?P[^ ]*) (?P[^ ]*) (?P[.|p]))?""", re.IGNORECASE)

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(36)()
>   -> f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-F',filename],\

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(37)()
>   -> stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(38)()
>   -> while True:

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(39)()
>   -> line = f.stdout.readline()

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(40)()
>   -> print line

(Pdb)
178.168.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2014:12:06:23 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 612 "-" "-" "-"

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(41)()
>   -> results = regex.match(line)

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(42)()
>   -> try:

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(43)()
>   -> print results.groups(request_time)

(Pdb)
AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'"

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(43)()
>   -> print results.groups(request_time)

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(44)()
>   -> except:

(Pdb)

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(45)()
>   -> print "Your expression does not match  this line"

(Pdb)
Your expression does not match  this line

> /opt/graphite/getResponce.py(38)()

Comment: I just [tested this on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8I9sBllIM5Yp7XKd), and it gives a nice error message explaining exactly what's wrong with it. So presumably you didn't test the same thing you used in your actual code; either the regex or the flags are different.

Comment: @abarnert Every question being posted on SO should inform the users that Debuggex and Regex101 exists.

Comment: yes removing the flag "re.x" matches on Debuggedx but doesn't work in my actually code

Comment: @Unihedron: The question does a great job linking to Debuggex. The problem is that the pattern in the linked Debuggex demo is not the same pattern in the code pasted here (and, presumably, in his actual code).

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. I think the problem lies outside the pattern, now that you've fixed the pattern syntax and the problem persists. Do you have an updated log entry?

Comment: If you use the `i` and `x` flags, as in the pasted code, it fails in Python, and Debuggex shows exactly why. If you use the `i` and `m` flags, as in the linked Debuggex demo, it works fine in both Python and Debuggex. I don't see why anyone is upvoting this, or trying to answer it. Different flags work differently; that's why they exist in the first place.

Comment: @Unihedron  i've updated the post with he debug output after removing "re.x" Thanks

Comment: 'Update: i've removed "re.X" and replace it with "re.verbose"'. First, `re.verbose` would just give you an `AttributeError`. Second, update the actual code in the question instead of just vaguely describing what you've changed. Third, why would you add the `VERBOSE` flag anyway if you're trying to match what you did on Debuggex, which didn't use that flag, and did use a different one? Fourth, if you used `VERBOSE` and didn't use `MULTILINE`, you should still get an exception in compiling the regex, so whatever you did is apparently not what you actually described.

Comment: And of course if I actually do use the pattern and flags you posted on Debuggex and test it on both the output in the original question and the output from that pdb session, it works just fine.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for your help, i think what i was trying to do was to narrow down why my regex was failing i was  thinking r.verbose would give me more detailed output, but it doesn't after researching only Whitespace is ignored and Comments are ignored, which is not what i'm after, so my regex in my code is now `(?P<host>[^ ]*) - - \[(?P<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?P<method>\S+)(?: +(?P<path>[^\"]*) +\S*)?" (?P<code>[^ ]*) (?P<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?P<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?P<agent>[^\"]*)")(?: (?P<request_time>[^ ]*) (?P<upstream_time>[^ ]*) (?P<pipe>[\.|p]))?`

Comment: @miggy282: OK, so why did you enable the `'m'` flag on Debuggex and not in your Python code? And, seeing that it works on Debuggex with the `'m'` flag and doesn't work in Python without it, and that you've explicitly been told that your code works in Python with that flag, why haven't you just added it?

Comment: @abarnert wasn't aware of the m flag on debuggx (my bad), but the main issue here is that the regex will match on debuggx and regex101 but will not work in my code so the question now is that could it be something else within my code? adding the m flag in my code doesn't make a difference

Comment: I don't know what to say. [Here](http://pastebin.com/K7DkAfS3) is the output from me copying and pasting exactly your pattern, with the `i` and `m` flags, and exactly your sample line and your line from the debugger. Given what's happened so far, my best guess is that either your pattern, your compile command, or your data are not what you say they are. One simple possibility: is there _more_ on each line than you're showing us? Maybe you want `re.search` rather than `re.match`?

Comment: @abarnert the log entries do differ `192.168.1.1 - - [08/Sep/2014:13:10:21 +0100]  "PROPFIND /<test> HTTP/1.1" 207 1203 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601" 0.026 0.026 .` thats one other output - so i guess that  the issue here is that the regex is  for a specific pattern only where my logfiles entries would differ

Comment: @miggy282: OK, do you know how to use Debuggex to debug your pattern so it fits your actual log messages? (Or, if you just copied and pasted this pattern from elsewhere, how to find one that applies to your actual logs…) If not, you may have a reasonable question—but then almost everything in the current question is irrelevant. Write an MCVE that demonstrates your actual problem, and where you're stuck, and you can get help.